# Struggling with some javascript, password / username error display

Tags: javascript

Note, I will validate everything with PHP on form submission, but I'd like to display it instantly to the user if possible.

For the username I am trying to detect if it only contains whitespace, if it's less than 8 chars/numbers and if it only contains normal valid letters and no symbols.

This does not seem to work:

```
$("#username").change(function() {
  $("#username").removeClass("error");
  var letterNumber = /^[0-9a-zA-Z]+$/;
  var username = $("#username").val(); // get value of password
  if (!(username.value.match(letterNumber)) {
    // return error
  }
  if (username.length < 8) {
    // return error
  }
  if (username.trim().length() > 0) {
    // return error
  }
});
```

And for the password, I want to allow all symbols, all numbers, all letters, minimum 8, and trim for whitespace. It does not seem to work though.

Comment: What is your question? One thing that jumps out is `username.trim()` should return > 0, the error should be returned if it's 0.

Comment: oh and it would be `username.trim().length`, no parens on length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change from this:

```
if (!(username.value.match(letterNumber)) {
    // return error
}
```

to this:

```
if (!(username.match(letterNumber)) {
    // return error
}
```

You've already retrieved the `.value` when you used `.val()` earlier so `username` is already the desired string.

---

Also, the `.trim()` test is not correct as `.length` is a property all by itself, not a method).  But, you can just remove this because your regex test before has already eliminated empty strings and strings with only whitespace so this test (even when corrected to be proper javascript) is unnecessary.

```
if (username.trim().length() > 0) {
    // return error
}
```

---

In the future, you should be looking in your browser error console or debug console because it would have told you something like undefined doesn't have a method `.match()` and given you that exact line number as the source of the error.

Comment: Tyvm, will do that in the futuere